# Visual Studio 2010 insets code snippet code on new line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, code-snippets

Assuming I want to create a code snippet for ToString(), I have created the following snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>To String VB</Title>
            <Author>John Doe</Author>
            <Description>Shortcut for ToString()</Description>
        <Shortcut>ts</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="VB">
                <![CDATA[toString()]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

When I write the code `myObject.ts` and then press tab to invoke the code snippet, visual studio does this:

```
myObject.
    toString()
```

instead of this:

```
myObject.toString()
```

How can I keep the snippet completion on the same line that I invoked it from? I came across a page that mentioned using `$end$` to mark the position the cursor should go when the snippet is inserted, but that has done nothing for me besides including the $end$ in the snippet.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using. I just tried this in 2015 (update 2) and it worked for me

Comment: @MattWilko I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I had the same issue. Placing $end$ worked for me. Where exactly did you insert it? Your code should look like this:
<![CDATA[toString()$end$]]>

Comment: Had the same issue with VS2019. Adding `$end$` at the end worked for me.